# Help with drawing custom graphics in Swing

Tags: java, swing, canvas, drawing

I know that i am not calling the graphics paint command in the mainframe in order to display it. but i'm not sure how.
thanks in advance

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private static Panel panel = new Panel();

public MainFrame() {
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.add(panel);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("abc", 20, 20);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples on painting as well as other Swing basics.

Also, don't use Panel, that is an AWT class. Use JPanel which is a Swing class.

Comment: ok now its working. so i needed to run super.paintComponent(g) with the paint class as a sub-class...or something like that...i'll keep playing with it. thanks

Comment: "with the paint class as a sub-class" -- This doesn't make sense. What are you trying to say here?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class that extends JComponent override the public void paintComponent(Graphics g) method and draw your string.

Add this overridded component to your frame.  Like: `frame.getContentPane().add(customComponent);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create your AWT / Swing stuff in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html). Second of all, you shouldn't be overriding paint on the main window. You need to create a subclass of `Component` and override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, putting in there whatever you have in `paint` at the moment. After this, add the component to the frame. You might need to mess with layout managers depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that extends JPanel like this:

```
 public class MyPanel extends JPanel{         
      public MyPanel(){
         setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("abc", 20, 20);
      }

 }
```

Then you can add that panel to your JFrame.

```
 public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

     private JPanel panel;

     public MainFrame() {
         panel = new MyPanel();    
         add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();

         frame.setSize(600, 400);
         frame.setResizable(false);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```